# Swift how to check user is typing or not in XMPP

Tags: swift, xmpp

First of all it may be a duplicate question, due to curiosity I asked.

I am creating a chatting application based on xmpp framework. Now I am facing issue, when a user typing I want its status will be sent to targeted user whom he chat.

I am using this code:

```
func sendComposingChat() {
    let sendToUser = strUserName + "@" + kAppDelegate.strJSenderDomain
    let sendFromUser = strMyUserName + "@" + kAppDelegate.strJDomain
    let messageBody = XMLElement.element(withName: "message") as! XMLElement
    messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "chat")
    messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "toUserId", stringValue: "1")
    messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "to", stringValue: sendToUser)
    messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "from", stringValue: sendFromUser)
    messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "senderId", stringValue: "1")

    let composing = XMLElement.element(withName: "composing") as! XMLElement
    composing.addAttribute(withName: "xmlns", stringValue: "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates")

    messageBody.addChild(composing)

    kAppDelegate.xmppStream?.send(messageBody)
}
```

On receiving the status I am managing in this way:

```
print("message = \(message.hasComposingChatState())")
let strComposing =  message.attribute(forName: "composing")?.stringValue
print("strComposing = \(strComposing)"
if strComposing?.characters.count == 0 {
     print("User is typing")
}
```

strComposing showing nil and I am not able to show typing status.

Please suggest what I am missing here.